# Calculate "rotated" position of children elements within a div (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, smartgwt

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this, I'm using a jquery plugin (jquery rotate) to rotate some elements inside a container, however a new crazy requirement came up and now I also need to rotate the container div, the problem is the children elements can be dragged and dropped inside this container and when it is rotated dragging stops working and it starts acting weird (I guess it makes sense as the coordinates system is being altered by the rotation on the container so the dragging behavior just goes crazy) so the only way that I can see to keep dragging and dropping working is to "simulate" the parent rotation by somehow calculate what the position of the children elements would be if the parent is rotated (without actually rotating the parent container) and position each child element on its corresponding final position, this way the coordinates system does not get "broken" and the drag and drop of the children remains working as expected.

To clarify what I'm trying to achieve lets suppose the container is 400x400px and that it has a children at top=0 and left=0, I would like to perform a "fake" 180 degrees rotation on the container that would send the child element to top=400px and left=400px (which is where the child element would visually end up being if the parent is rotated), I'm hoping there is   a library I can use to perform this math (math is not my thing though) on each children and somehow "calculate" or "determine" the position they should have within the container if it is rotated 180 degrees and then position each children where they should be (the container rotation will always be a 180 degrees rotation which means it will be either at a "normal" angle of 0 degrees or a "flipped" angle of 180 degrees).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to put up a JSFiddle with some sample code of what you have so far?

Comment: It's a bit difficult, the markup is a very complex DOM tree generated by SmartGWT, let me see if I can simplify it and put together and "clean" markup that illustrates the example... the biggest issue with setting up a jsfiddle is the drag and drop is implemented by SmartGWT (god knows how) and I would need to implement it using some sort of jquery way like Draggable or something like that which might not produce the same behavior I'm actually seeing within SmartGwt